# Tkinter Collision Detection

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to code collision detection between objects in tkinter for my coursework (unfortunately we cannot use pygame). I have a red square and a black square and I move the red square, and I want the black square to delete when the red square overalaps with it. However this doesn't happen as when I overlap the red square into the black square, the latter doesn't delete. How do I fix this?

```
    import tkinter as tk 
    from tkinter import *
    
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("1366x768")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = 1300, height = 700)
    
    rec1 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150, fill = "black") #black rectangle
    mover = canvas.create_rectangle(400, 400, 450, 450, fill = "red", outline = "red")  #red moving rectangle
    
    canvas.pack() 
    
    def left(event):
        x = -10
        y = 0 
        canvas.move(mover, x, y)
        
    def right(event):
        x = 10
        y = 0 
        canvas.move(mover, x, y)
    
    def up (event):
        x = 0
        y = -10 
        canvas.move(mover, x, y)
    
    def down(event):
        x = 0
        y = 10 
        canvas.move(mover, x, y)
    
    window.bind("<Left>", left)
    window.bind("<Right>", right)
    window.bind("<Up>", up )
    window.bind("<Down>", down)
    
    a = canvas.bbox(1) # coordinates of the black rectangle
    b = canvas.bbox(2) # coordinates of the red, moving rectangle
    
    if b[0] in range(a[0],a[2]) or b[2] in range(a[0],a[2]) and b[1] in range(a[1],a[3]) or b[3] in range(a[1],a[3]):
        canvas.delete(rec1)  #if they overlap, then delete the static black rectangle
    
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `if` statement only executes once, before the window is even visible.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok that makes sense. Do you know how I can fix the problem? I replaced the 'if' word with 'while' yet that didn't work either.

Comment: Put the code in a function, and call that function whenever the objects move.